# In this SwiftUI example why is opacity not working on an Image?

Tags: swiftui

Why doesn't .opacity() have any effect in this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    @State private var selectedOption = 1
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Menu {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) {option in
                    Button {
                        selectedOption = option
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(option)")
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .opacity(option == selectedOption ? 1 : 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Selected option")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(selectedOption)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code all of the menu items have a checkmark.

But if I wrap the Image in an `if option == selectedOption`  and leave out `.opacity` it works as expected.

I get the same results in the preview, on a simulator, and on a real device.

Apple has a nearly identical example here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/choosing-the-right-way-to-hide-a-view

Comment: Your code works as expected. When `showCheckmark = false` the opacity is zero and there is no checkmark. When the `showCheckmark = true`, opacity is 1 and there is a checkmark. Tested on real ios17 devices and MacCatalyst.

Comment: I think the above code works fine, maybe it's because of showCheckmark property you've passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Menu` ignores any styling on the menu content. Try this and see NO effect :)

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark")
    .bold()
    .opacity(0)
    .foregroundStyle(.red)
```

You can do this:

```
Image(systemName: selectedOption == option ? "" : "checkmark")
```

But when running on a real device you'll get this in the console:

```
No symbol named '' found in system symbol set
```

It might be better to go with this:

```
if option == selectedOption {
    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
}
```

Comment: As a SwiftUI newbie I'm just wondering if that is documented anywhere.

Comment: @MurraySagal thanks for the edit! I don't know of a clear documentation of this, I found out by trying, and of course this community. There are tons of questions regarding colouring of menu items and its limitations here.